# trouble with my advanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I want my program to search for an objects id (once) and then change the quantity with my replenish() method but it requires i type in the id multiple times before it works, how do i fix this?

```
import java.util.*;

class TestPart {



   public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
         parts.add(new Part("p122", "Chain", 48, 12.50));
         parts.add(new Part("p123", "Chain Guard", 73, 22.00));
         parts.add(new Part("p124", "Crank", 400, 11.50));
         parts.add(new Part("p125", "Pedal", 38, 6.50));
         parts.add(new Part("p126", "Handlebar", 123, 9.50));
         System.out.println("part before stock level change - start");
         System.out.println(Part.toString(parts));
         System.out.println("To replenish type 'R' or to supply type 'S'");
         String choice = sc.nextLine();
         for(int i = 0; i<1; i++) {
             if (choice.equals("R")){
                System.out.println("Please enter ID of part you would like "
                        + "to replenish");

                for (Part part: parts) 
                    {
                     if(part!=null && sc.nextLine().equals(part.getID())){
                        System.out.println("Please enter replenish quantity");
                        part.replenish(sc.nextInt());
                     }
                }
             } else { 
                 System.out.println("You did not type 'R' or 'S'");
             }
         }
         /*System.out.println("Please enter ID");
         //parts.get(1).replenish(sc.nextInt());
        for (Part part: parts) {
             if(part!=null && sc.nextLine().equals(part.getID())){
                System.out.println("Please enter replenish quantity");
                part.replenish(sc.nextInt());
             }
         }*/
         System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
         System.out.println("part after stock level change - start");
         System.out.println(Part.toString(parts));
         System.out.println("end");

         sc.close();
     }

}
```

The output works but just after "Please enter ID of part you would like to replenish" i have to type in the part ID 5 times, for example. p126 p126 p126 p126 p126. then it will prompt for replenish quantity. Why is it asking for the ID 5 times? and how do i make it just once

Comment: Side note on code quality: you are doing way too many things within one method. On top of that: don't use static main methods for testing; instead learn how to write **unit tests**. Believe me, the relatively small amount of time required to get into unit testing will pay off very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Jägermeister! i will deffinetely look into learning how to write unit tests for the future. At the moment, for this part of my assignment (for uni) one method will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bad idea basically to put this part of code :

```
sc.nextLine().equals(part.getID())
```

into a loop because `sc.nextLine()` wait an input from the user each time it is called.

Try this :

```
             if (choice.equals("R")){
                System.out.println("Please enter ID of part you would like "
                        + "to replenish");
                String input = sc.nextLine();
                for (Part part: parts) 
                    {
                     if(part!=null && input.equals(part.getID())){
                        System.out.println("Please enter replenish quantity");
                        part.replenish(sc.nextInt());
                     }
                }
             }
```

You'll be asked once and will have to put it in once. It is then stored in a `String` variable. Whenever you need it again, use the variable.

Comment: oh yes i see. same way to how i had done it for the choice variable? Thank You!

Comment: @danielb yes, exactly